# How to get a post ID php using js

Tags: javascript, php

here I want to display the data id based on the click button using js

my code:

```
var idPost = document.getElementsByClassName("getID")[0];
idPost.onclick = function() {
    var GetID = window.location.protocol + "//" 
                + window.location.host 
                + window.location.pathname 
                + '?id=<?php echo $id;?>';
    window.history.pushState({ path: GetID }, '', GetID );
}
```

why my code isn't working?
maybe someone here can help my problem

Comment: with some sweet ajax

Comment: If you got da' skills, AJAX pays da' bills @treyBake

Comment: `history.pushState` pushes a new state to the history - that’s it. It doesn’t load any content - doing that yourself in the background, and putting it into the current document, would be your responsibility. Or, you could just assign the new URL to `location.href` - then this would be a real navigation action, automatically causing a request to the server to load a new document to display.

Comment: Btw, prefixing `window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host` is kinda superfluous - relative URLs exist.

Comment: you can use jquery and send id with ajax call.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice you all gave. I will try later using ajax

Answer (score 0):

This may will help you:

EDIT

`location.href` reloads page to indicated `url`

```
var idPost = document.getElementsByClassName("getID")[0];
idPost.onclick = function() {
    let id = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
    location.href = `?id=${id}`;
}
```